# Call Web service with jQuery and Parameters

Tags: jquery, json, asmx

I'm having trouble when calling an ASMX web service through jQuery. I can paste this URL in my browser to get the XML results desired:

```
http://<serverurl>/WebService/ReportServer.asmx/RowDataWithFilterParamsAndColumnParams?filterParams=EXCAVATION_DIG.EXCAVATION_DIG_INTL_ID%20IN%20(1)&columnParams=Dig_ID|Line|Dig_Type|Dig_Status
```

I can call the asmx from a Console application like this without no issue:

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string results = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
```

What I'm having trouble with is calling the web service from the client side. What is wrong with my code? I don't get any errors but the success function is not called.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var url = "http://<serverurl>/WebService/ReportServer.asmx/RowDataWithFilterParamsAndColumnParams";
var payload = "{ filterParams : 'EXCAVATION_DIG.EXCAVATION_DIG_INTL_ID%20IN%20(1)',  columnParams : 'Dig_ID|Line|Dig_Type|Dig_Status' }";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: payload, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",              
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        }
    });

});
```

When I change the data type to "json" I get the error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is add the error callback to your AJAX function. You need to read the response which holds the error. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

What I suspect you will find is that you are restricted to domain for security purposes. There is still hope and it is called CORS.

http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Also note the variable "crossDomain" in the ajax function. It must be set to true to enable CORS. Some scenarios will require jsonpcallback due to timing issues.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: payload, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",            
        crossDomain: true,  
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        },
        error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Unless you are sure the site allows cross-domain connection which is rare then you may be out of luck. If it expects JSONP (very different from JSON) as you set in your function then do you know the callback function being passed back? Look back at the jQuery API more carefully. There is a lot of details you must understand for this type of connection.

Comment: I added the .fail() function but how can I pass the error as a parm?  The following returns [object]

.fail(function(err) {
  alert( err );
 });

Comment: I am not sure which version of jQuery you are using, but since you are using but I will edit my answer to show you the error function equivalent to success. If you are usng a new version of then you should not be using the success function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error -- basically, a script in a browser can't request a resource from a server other than the one the page was originally served from, unless the server allows all external requests, or explicitly whitelists your domain.

So, you can do this from the server-side, but not from the client-side unless

1. you control the server and can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with `*` (allow everyone) or a list of whitelisted domains, or,
2. you can go through a CORS proxy, which is set up to allow calls from any domain, and then re-execues the call from the proxy's server side, whcih is not subject to CORS limitations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access the server code. I tried using CORS with no luck. Do you have a sample of how mine would look?

Comment: If you can't change the server code, you won't be able to talk to that service from a browser. If you have your own server in the mix, you can send the call to your to a CORS proxy on your server, which would then contact the target server, get the data and relay it back to your browser code. Or, you could use one of the hosted CORS proxies to do the same without having to write or install a proxy on your server -- look at e.g. https://jsonp.afeld.me/